# Is ES6 a good choice over ES5 to develop a desktop(electron) app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am developing a data science app that uses codes from python, R in the backend and for the frontend, I am using HTML, CSS, and js. By using electron framework I would like to make it into a desktop application. The role of js mainly, to read the files generated by R/python codes and produce interactive d3 plots. Speed is also one of my concern, I was wondering should I use ES6 or ES5? I have read that ES6 code gets transpiled into ES5 so that Node can run it natively. Does it mean that even if ES6 is used to develop the app, it will still run at the speed of ES5?

Thanks

Comment: ES6 will in general be slower than ES5. All those new features slow the interpreter down, rather than to speed it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't be transpiled by Electron, you'd have to do that yourself.  So feel free to use the latest features of ES6 without worrying about performance issues.

According to the [official website](https://www.electronjs.org/), Electron runs `v12.14.1` of Node.  You can see [here](https://node.green/) that Node supports most ES6 features.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, can you please cite a reference.

Comment: I added a couple references.